# Access anonymous type variable after declare it

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a method which has anonymous type and after it I add parameters to viewmodel.

```
public void ConvertirBono(List<Bono> ParamBonos,List<Empleado> ParamEmpleado)
{
    Bonos = new List<BonoVM>();

    var bonos2 = ParamBonos.Where(x => x.mdEstatusRegistro)
        .Join(ParamEmpleado, x => x.EmpleadoID, y => y.ID, (x, y) => new
    {
        empleadoCompleto = y.nCodigoEmpleado.ToString() + y.vNombreEmpleado,
    }).ToList();
    foreach (var p in ParamBonos)
    {
        Bonos.Add(new BonoVM()
        {
            EmpleadoId = p.EmpleadoID,
            vEmpleado = empleadoCompleto,
            nBono1 = p.nBono1,
            nBono2 = p.nBono2
        });
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to insert anonymous type `empleadoCompleto` when I add  into ViewModel(foreach clause) but it always comes null. I try to declare that variable outside but it still comes null.

```
public void ConvertirBono(List<Bono> ParamBonos,List<Empleado> ParamEmpleado)
{
    Bonos = new List<BonoVM>();
    string empleadoCompleto = null;

    var bonos2 = ParamBonos.Where(x => x.mdEstatusRegistro)
        .Join(ParamEmpleado, x => x.EmpleadoID, y => y.ID, (x, y) => new
    {
        empleadoCompleto = y.nCodigoEmpleado.ToString() + y.vNombreEmpleado,
    }).ToList();
    foreach (var p in ParamBonos)
    {
        Bonos.Add(new BonoVM()
        {
            EmpleadoId = p.EmpleadoID,
            vEmpleado = empleadoCompleto,
            nBono1 = p.nBono1,
            nBono2 = p.nBono2
        });
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `empleadoCompleto` isn't an anonymous type, it's just a string variable. I don't think you understand what an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) is. In your code, the line `empleadoCompleto = y.nCodigoEmpleado...` isn't assigning anything to the string variable, it's creating a property in an anonymous type with the same name.

Comment: Yes but how can I use that variable into foreach clause?@DavidG

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. What are you expecting the `bonos2` object to contain here?

Comment: use variable of anonymouse type into foreach clause in  `vEmpleado = empleadoCompleto` I also try bonos2.empleadoCompleto  but isn't work @DavidG

Comment: Stop focussing on anonymous types, that's got nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it looks like all you are trying to do it merge the two list objects together and create a list of view models. There's no need to create anonymous types here at all, you can do it all with one line of code. This may not be quite right as your question is unclear, but it should at least get you on the right track.

```
public void ConvertirBono(List<Bono> ParamBonos,List<Empleado> ParamEmpleado)
{
    Bonos = ParamBonos.Where(x => x.mdEstatusRegistro)
        .Join(ParamEmpleado, 
            x => x.EmpleadoID, 
            y => y.ID, 
            (x, y) => new BonoVM
            {
                EmpleadoId = x.EmpleadoID,
                vEmpleado = y.nCodigoEmpleado.ToString() + y.vNombreEmpleado,
                nBono1 = x.nBono1,
                nBono2 = x.nBono2
            })
        .ToList();
}
```